# Can't able to play an audio after receiving a silent push notification in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using this below code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

pushcome=NO;

pushcome=[self registerForPushNotification:launchOptions];


[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
 return YES;
}
```

And below code is for receiving push:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
NSLog(@"BACK GROUND MODE PUSH");
if([userInfo[@"aps"][@"content-available"] intValue]== 1) //it's the silent notification
{

    [self saveInUserDefault];

 stkaudioPlayer = [[STKAudioPlayer alloc]init]; //player initialize

    //Save audio url
    NSString *str= [userInfo valueForKey:@"AudioURL"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:str forKey:@"forUrl"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // for Playing an audio using 'Avplayer' ==>
NSString *finalUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"forUrl"]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:finalUrl];
    playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    [player play];
    // <===
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

NSLog(@"==Hi, I am from silent Notification ========%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"forUrl"]);
    return;
}
else
{

    NSLog(@"User ... %@",userInfo);
        return;
}
}
```

I am getting the following error:-

**[0x37fd8000] >aurioc> 807: failed: '!int' (enable 2, outf< 2 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16, inter> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, non-inter>**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For push notification sound
You need to use this code**

```
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef ref = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle,      (CFStringRef)@"mysound.wav", NULL, NULL);
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(ref, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```